# Sci-fi series from 2000s with alien-like characters and a character resembling fire

Tags: story-identification, tv

As a child I watched a couple of episodes of a sci-fi series set on a planet, that was far from resembling Earth - I remember a dark, stoney scenery and tanks of some form. It was probably in English, and it was a 3D animated series.

The only thing I really remember is a character that was burning, it was basically a walking fire with black eyes and flames instead of hair, the entire being just burned and it was orange/yellow- a fire.
And then there were some sort of aliens or alien-like creatures, a father and a son, or a father and a daughter. in some way they resembeled bugs. The ''fireman'', and those two aliens were the ''good guys'' of the series, but I can't remember what they fought against or ran away of...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Anything else you can remember about this series - what country was it made in, what language was it in?

Comment: It was probably in english, and it was a 3D animated seires.

Comment: [This list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer-animated_television_series) and [this one](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AllCGICartoon) might be helpful. I feel like the number of all 3D animated series from the 2000s is probably low enough to just sift through them by hand.

Comment: Yes i found it on the first list! It's called Shadow Raiders! I had it in my head that the title had to do something with Shadows, but no matter how hard I searched I couldn't find it! 
Thank you so so much, this has been bothering for years, though I've forgot about it, but I've dreamt about it tonight and I simply had to find it! 
You saved my childhood, I almost gave up thinking i made everything up! 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @woodentable You can (and should) answer your own question, then come back in 48 hours and accept it. Glad you found it!